# Chaining moveLoc calls

Tags: lua, moai

I'm trying to chain a series of moveLoc calls, but I can't seem to do it without getting jerky/hitchy movements (in between calls).

```
-- executed in a separate thread
while moving do    
  action = prop:moveLoc(x, y, speed, MOAIEaseType.EASE_IN)
  MOAICoroutine.blockOnAction(action)  
  coroutine.yield() 
end
```

What I am trying to achieve is, have the **prop** continuously move by **x**, **y** with the **speed** under the condition that **moving** is true. (Also when **moving** is false, it is alright to finish up remaining movements, it does not have to stop on the point **moving** turns false)

The animation I'm seeing in the result pauses very now and then between the calls

Moves -> Stops -> Moves -> Stops -> Moves ...

How can I reduce the pauses in between moveLoc calls and have the prop move continuously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probably want `MOAIEaseType.LINEAR`, or just use `setLoc` and update the position manually.